# Декомпозировать предметную область?

Tags: ооп, анализ

Что мне надо сделать, чтобы хорошо декомпозировать предметную область? Еще я хочу оценить это.

Я читал 'Head First Object Oriented Analysis and Design' , 'Sams Teach Yourself UML in 24 Hours (Joseph Schmuller)', и многие статьи.

Как мне это практиковать? Хочу чуть-чуть углубиться. (Не говорите, что пиши программу.)

Не могу хорошо определить для себя. Для меня это дилемма.
(Этот вопрос Вообще принадлежит 'Responsibility Assignment').

Comment: Чтобы хорошо декомпозировать предметную область (и вообще чтобы что-то хорошо делать) - нужен опыт. Единственный надежный способ получения опыта - писать программы.

Comment: @PashaPash Спасибо за ответ может ещё какие-то книги или что-то другое ?

Comment: А ты хочешь книги читать, или все же получать опыт?

Comment: @bukkojot ответ нашёл практиковал. Спасибо и практикуюсь

Answer (score -2):

> Как мне это практиковать? Хочу чуть-чуть углубиться. Не говорите, что
>   пиши программу.

Пиши программу. Вот прямо сейчас бери и пейши. Еще лучше напроситься в какой-то проект или в компанию на стажировку.

Правда бывает так, что реальных целей нет, или совсем непонятно как их решать. Потому появляется прокрастинация в виде курсов/книг/совещаний,  создается впечатление, что все идет правильно, что так и надо, но код, само собой, никто даже не начинает писать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. первым долгом я работаю. Я прошёл этот переход , кратко порекомендую только разрабатывать программы это не хватает (как я прошел) мне помогло "практика + GOF + Code Complete + Head First OOAD + Head First DP + Object Oriented Software Construction + Adaptive Code via C# Agile coding with design patterns and solid principles". Ну ещё не прочитал осталось 3 книги .) эти книги очень помогли мне.